# Android Threads and Asynchronus tasks

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

So I have a thread, lets call it connectedThread it receives data from a input stream (could be anything Bluetooth, wifi, usb serial etc), what I wanted to know is how do I send a interrupt to the thread which causes it hold on until a certain method in the same thread (connectedThread) is finished generating results. See the below pseudo code to help illustrate my point.

## Connected Thread:

```
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        //Bluetooth socket just a example could be any input stream.
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer; // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    // Arbitrary size for input stream data buffer. 
                    buffer = new byte[3];
                    //Send a arbitrary command for device to respond 
                    mmOutStream.write(255);
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
                    /* This is where I want to not hard code a time out but in fact,
                     * wait for mmInStream.read(buffer,0,buffer.length); 
                     * to finish then immediately proceed 
                     */
                    Thread.sleep(87);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the message handler
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ,buffer).sendToTarget();
                    }
                 catch (IOException e) {
                     break;
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         }
        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

}
```

## Summary

So as I suggested in the code comments above. I want the current executing thread to wait for the input stream data to finish filling up the buffer then immediately send the results to the message handler. In particular I do not want to use the Thread.sleep() command as this slows down the process. I have already read the following [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) intensely but haven't found a solution to my problem.

Comment: `mmInStream.read` is done when it returns.

Comment: Read is already a blocking call and you loop in it, so I'm not sure what you're getting at, there's no `Thread.sleep()` needed.

Comment: @Dan S & immibis, thats what I thought too. I am working on a bigger [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291049/android-bluetooth-arduino). If I don't use sleep then my app does not update an array's values accurately, and thats got me stumped. Because only after the read() function is finished should the message oject be sent to the handler right?

Comment: Yes but if you need multiple reads that could be a problem. It is just as valid for a stream to come in a single byte at a time as it is for whole buffers at a time.

Comment: @ Dan S: that's exactly what I am doing. I am reading live data, repeatedly until the user chooses to close the app. Can you please elaborate on your comment ? Also is there a efficient workaround to read live updating data?

Comment: Without using `java.nio` for an arbitrary socket protocol or `AndroidHTTPClient` for HTTP, this is the best way of doing it. What I really am unclear about is: What do you want the interrupt to do for you?

Comment: @DanS the way I solved the problem was reading one byte at a time. I removed Thread.sleep, and asked the connected micro-controller to send one byte(write 255 read 255 write 254 read 254 etc) of data at a time, each byte representing something different ofcourse. I have know idea still why reading a buffer of size 3 at a time compared to a size of one would make a difference.Any ideas? The only reason plausible was the way the Bluetooth protocol handles packet lose and acknowledgments behind the scene (like TCP)?

Comment: My best guess is that the buffer wasn't being filled.